# SplitDateTime field and widget with datetimefield in models

Tags: django, datetime, internationalization

I have a model with a datetimefield in django.

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()
```

and a model form for the above model

```
class EntryAddForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        exclude = ('creator','canceled', 'reason',)
        widgets = {
            'start': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-append date',
                                      'id':'datetimepicker1'}),
            'end': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-append date',
                                    'id':'datetimepicker2'}),
            'title': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'snippet': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'body':Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'customer': Select(attrs={'class':'form-control selectpicker',
                                      'data-live-search':'true'})

        }
```

I ran on to SplitDateTime field...and said....wow this is what i want. I want the user to be able to enter date and time seperately but on the backend to always have a datetimefield that is aware of time zone. So i tried this.

```
'start': SplitDateTimeWidget(attrs = {'class':'form-control input-append date'
                                      'id': datetimepicker1'}),
```

and the same for the end field. But what i got is two fields stuck to each other and with only one label. I can't find a good doc or tutorial about MultiWidgets. What I want to do is:

- Have separate labels for each widget (as in Start Date Start Time, End Date, End Time)
- Add a specific class to each one differently (The date and the time fields)

Is it possible with this widget? Is it better to create four form fields (start date start time end date, end time) and asign them the values of the start and end fields on the constructor, and overide save to "construct" a datetime field from the four fields? I need datetime aware objects cause of internationalization. Searched the web but couldn't find best practice

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be possible to do what you want with a MultiWidget... although the field will only have one label from Django's perspective there is nothing to stop you adding anything in the html output for the widget.

See also:

[How do I use Django's MultiWidget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511855/how-do-i-use-djangos-multiwidget)

http://bradmontgomery.blogspot.co.uk/2008/11/extending-djangos-multiwidget.html